# Returning pointer to global array from function

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, memory

I am not experienced enough in C/C++ programming, so I am asking for an explanation.

I have global array declared as following. ASAK it is located in seperate memory part of initialized global memory in context of process memory.

```
Sensor sensorsArray[SENSORS_COUNT] = {dhtTempSensor, dhtHumSensor, dallasTempSensor, waterLevelSensor};
```

I need to find element in this array and return pointer to it (because I am going to change its value). I have written such function.

```
Sensor* getSensorById(uint32_t id) {
  for (int i = 0; i < SENSORS_COUNT; i++) {
    Sensor* current = &sensorsArray[i];
    if (current->sensorId == id) {
      return current;
    }
  }
}
```

Will it work properly, I am not sure about `current` pointer, it is allocated on the stack so it is in function scope, will it be poped from the stack after function ends ? Or it will work properly.

I mean not pointer(address of array element which is taken using &sensorsArray[i]), but current pointer variable which contains address of erray element, will it be poped or not.

Please suggest best way how to do in such situation.
Thx.

Comment: I think what you are doing is OK. I would just add a 'return nullptr;' at the end of the function, in case you do not find a sensor given the ID

Comment: What if the id isn't found?

Comment: Why not use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)?

Comment: `return current` returns the *value* of `current`, so that's OK. The thing you aren't allowed to do is return the address of current: `return &current` would not work.

Comment: @NathanOliver: your advice is 'learn C++ without learning C first', right? I would like to know fwzfhxhoryfs opinion...

Comment: Thanks for answers !!!  Really helped

Comment: What does “ASAK” mean? Please try to avoid unnecessary abbreviations.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't covering all the possible returning cases of the function, namely, the case when the `id` does not match with any of the `id`s of the array.

Currently the pointer will return the last element of the array if there is no match.

You could correct that by defining the pointer `Sensor* sensor_found = nullptr` outside the `for` loop such that if there is no sensor found the return value is still valid, i.e. `nullptr` and assigning the found value of `current` to `sensor_found`, only if there is a match.

```
Sensor* getSensorById(uint32_t id) {

    Sensor* sensor_found = nullptr;

    for (int i = 0; i < SENSORS_COUNT; i++) {

        Sensor* current = &sensorsArray[i]; 

        if (current->sensorId == id) {
             sensor_found = current;  
             break;    
        }
    }

    return sensor_found;
}
```

If the `id` found return `current`, otherwise, if there is no match return `nullptr`.

Answer (score 1):

you want to make sure that the function has a valid return statement on its every execution path. In you current implementation if the id is not matched then the return value of Sensor* is not set and will contain random bytes. One wau to deal with this situation is to return the nullptr to indicate that  the Sensor was not found. Other than that, ythe function will work properly.

```
Sensor* getSensorById(uint32_t id) {
  for (int i = 0; i < SENSORS_COUNT; i++) {
    Sensor* current = &sensorsArray[i];
    if (current->sensorId == id) {
      return current;
    }
  }
  return nullptr;  // id not matched
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine (as the comments suggest). The reason why you don't need to worry about the `current` pointer becoming invalid is because the memory that it points to (ie, the global array) stays valid beyond the scope of the function. Just because you happen to create a pointer (and remember, a pointer is really just a number that corresponds to some place in memory) to that memory doesn't mean that it becomes invalid when used elsewhere.

When you say `Sensor *current = &sensorArray[i];`, then if `sensorArray[i]` is stored at, say, position `0x10` in memory, then `current = 0x10`, and no matter where it is used, then `sensorArray[i]` will still be at memory location `0x10`. When you assign a value to `current`, you are not copying the value from the sensor, you are merely getting a pointer to it.